# Stackoverflow System

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

I am sorry if this question is off topic. I wanted to know if there is a page where users can learn more about Stackoverflow's system architecture, for example the kind of templating system it uses etc..

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: @Mysticial thanks for the link. I have a little question may be you can help. They use ASP.NET. Why is it that the pages don't have .asp extensions?  Can you give me a little explanation about ? thanks

Comment: Don't ask me. I don't run the site and I know nothing about asp.net.

Comment: @edd - People sometimes opt not to show file extensions for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments and answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blog post that @him linked to is great but [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network) seems to be updated regularly as changes are made to the network systems.

- [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Answer (score 2):

There is a blog for that: [What Was Stack Overflow Built With?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)